# How to start new Thread to continue work when Sleep is called within a Thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am creating a Thread calling a custom compare method within a class - FastestComparator.java

The Thread Class:

```
public class FastestComparatorThread extends Thread {

    private int valueToFind;
    private List<CustomNumberEntity> list;
    private FastestComparator fastComparator = new FastestComparator();
    private int result = 1;

    public FastestComparatorThread(int valueToFind, List<CustomNumberEntity> list) {
        this.valueToFind = valueToFind;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (CustomNumberEntity customNumberEntity : list) {
            try {
                synchronized(fastComparator) {
                    result = fastComparator.compare(valueToFind, customNumberEntity);
                    System.out.println(result);
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

The Compare Method has a Sleep function within it:

```
public int compare(int firstValue, CustomNumberEntity secondValue){
        Random random = new Random();
        int mSeconds = (random.nextInt(6)+5)*1000; //milliseconds
        int secondValueAsNumber = Integer.parseInt(secondValue.getNumber());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(mSeconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //error while sleeping. Do nothing.
        }
        return firstValue-secondValueAsNumber;
    }
```

Currently, after starting the Thread, I am calling the interrupt() method, while the Thread isAlive() essentially to avoid the sleep after starting the Thread

```
FastestComparatorThread fastestComparatorThread = new FastestComparatorThread(valueToFind, list);
fastestComparatorThread.start();

while(fastestComparatorThread.isAlive()) {
    fastestComparatorThread.interrupt();
    if (fastestComparatorThread.getResult() == 0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of kicking off a new thread that continues the work when the first one sleeps instead of continuously interrupting the one Thread?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `sleep()` call? Why don't you just remove it?

Comment: Soley for the purpose of trying to understand/learn about multithreading

Comment: guess you want signal kind of thing...

Comment: I posted an answer (below), but I'm guessing that my answer won't help you to figure out whatever question you have that underlies the "sleep" question. You say that calling `sleep()` was supposed to help you "understand/learn about multithreading." How so? Sleep is dirt simple (see my answer). Are you, perhaps using the `sleep()` call to _simulate_ something else that is going to take significant time? If so, what is the activity that you're simulating?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of `synchronized(fastComparator)`? Does any other thread also "synchronize" on that object?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way of kicking off a new thread that continues the work when the first one sleeps...?

No. The `Thread.sleep(nnnn)` call does nothing. It does nothing for approximately `nnnn` milliseconds (but never *less* than `nnnn` milliseconds), and then it returns. There is no provision in Java for one thread to be automatically notified when some other thread calls `sleep()`.